# Migrate d2d UI Comment Fields

Tags: migrations

Running Drupal-to-Drupal 7.x-2.1.  I am attempting to migrate d6 comment attachments to d7 using the UI.  In d6, I used the Comment Upload module for comment attachments.  d7 does not have such a module, but you can attach files to comments by adding a file field to the comment structure.

I created migration code which provides the source file field information I need (from the d6 comment_upload table).  I created a file field in the d7 destination content type comment structure.

However, when I run the Drupal import option in the d2d UI and navigate to the destination map for the content type comment in question, I do not see the file field I created.

Is this normal?  A bug?

I have seen a 'solution' to migrating files attached to comments from d6 to d7 advertised here, but after following 3 links, it only provides a vague explanation with examples of core node file migration.  There is no example, or logic, provided to show how to actually map a d6 file field to a d7 comment file field.

My hope was to be able to do this through the d2d ui, but it does not appear to display comment file fields.

Any help on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug.  I ran the import the first time, then discovered that I was migrating nodes to the wrong content type, so ran it again with the correct content type.

Thing is, if you don't configure your destination content type as allowing comments, then comment migration will be skipped for all sources mapped to that destination.

So, I thought d2d ui wasn't working correctly when all the time it was my configuration.  Oops!